# Changing the "go" key on iPad keyboard

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I am developing in phonegap, and I have a chat window with an input field like so:

```
<div class="chatWindow"></div>
<form>
   <input type="text">
   <input type="submit" onclick="sendChatMsg();return false;">
</form>
```

I've found that adding the attribute `title="Search"` to the text input field produces a "search" button on the iPad keyboard instead of the standard "go" button. However I want this button to be named either "send" or "return".

If the field is not within a `<form>` tag then the return button is automatically picked, but then the text input is not linked to the submit button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out how to add the "return" key on text-input, by using `<textarea>` for input (uses "return" as default") and triggering on enter like so:

```
            $(".chatMsgArea").keydown(function(){
                if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                    sendChatMsg();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

This allows for the return key to be present rather than "go" or "search" and it appears that this is the way pintrest and facebook are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would probably be to write a phonegap plugin.

you would need to write some callable code to do the following

For a `UITextField` or editable `UITextView`:

```
[myTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyGo];
```

Them edit the 'Go' button's functionality accordingly

Comment: This is a bit extensive to just add a "return" button for an input field, I found a cheaper way to do so.